# ExtJS material theme is not working

Tags: javascript, extjs

I'm using ExtJS 6.2.1. The problem I face is that material theme breaks the whole layout of my page, which consits just of one window widget. That is how I include material theme to my page:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/ext-6.2.1/build/modern/theme-material/resources/theme-material-all.css" type="text/css" />
```

And this how it looks like:

[image]

If however I switch to triton theme like so:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/ext-6.2.1/build/classic/theme-triton/resources/theme-triton-all.css" type="text/css" />
```

Everything starts to work:

[image]

So, what is wrong with that and how can I fix it?

Comment: So you are not using Sencha Cmd to build your application? Because the different theme is being set completely differently.

Comment: @pagep. I do not use. So, what is the right way to link material theme to the project? Without using Cmd. Thanks!

Comment: I always used bootstrap and microloader. I am not sure what are the steps without it, I guess you don't have any app.json where you can set-up the theme? It's obvious that the material CSS are not loaded at all in your case.

Comment: Just a wild guess: Somehow, the `theme-material-all.css` file does not make its way to the web app, so you have no theme at all? Use the browser's developer tools to check.

Comment: I have it. I even see, that this file is loaded

Comment: Assuming the app is built in classic, you can't apply the material theme (a modern theme) to a classic app.

Comment: Please put network console of all loaded css/files , we can have better idea from it.Because some other file might be overriding css contents.

Comment: What toolkit are you using, classic/modern/both ?

Comment: you have to use sencha Cmd(sencha app watch or sencha app refresh)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You cannot use a modern-toolkit theme on a classic-toolkit application.They both have different components & different config properties.

For example, in classic toolkit we have `Ext.window.Window` component. But modern-toolkit has `Ext.MessageBox` component which does the same job.For giving label text,we use `fieldLabel` in classic-toolkit whereas `label` in modern-toolkit.

So,modern-toolkit theme will contain styles of components supported by modern-kit only.It doesn't have styles of classic-toolkit components.That's why you are getting output.
To achieve same output,the overall code differs in both the toolkits.Just see the popup example below designed both in classic & modern toolkit.

**Classic-toolkit Popup**

```
Ext.create('Ext.window.Window', {
    title: 'Login',
width: 400,
    items:   [{
                    xtype: 'textfield',
                    fieldLabel: 'User Name',
                    width:'100%',
                },
                {
                    xtype: 'textfield',
                    width:'100%',
                    fieldLabel: 'Password',
                }],
                buttons:[{text:'Login'}]
}).show();
```

**Modern-toolkit Popup**

```
Ext.create('Ext.MessageBox', { // window changes to messagebox
    title: 'Login',
width: 400,
    items:   [{
                    xtype: 'textfield',
                    label: 'User Name', //fieldLabel changes to label
                    width:'100%',
                },
                {
                    xtype: 'textfield',
                    width:'100%',
                    label: 'Password',
                }],
                buttons:[{text:'Login'}]
}).show();
```

Comment: Classic toolkit theming: https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.2.1/guides/core_concepts/theming.html

Modern toolkit theming: https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.2.1/guides/core_concepts/modern_theming.html